# Extract valid words from a text file PHP

Tags: php, dictionary, words, pspell

I have created a PHP code that extracts valid words form a text file :

```
$pspell_link = pspell_new("en");
$handle = fopen("list.txt", "r");

if ($handle) {
            while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {

                    $line = str_replace(' ', '', $line);
                    $line = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $line);

                    if (pspell_check($pspell_link, $line)) 
                    {
                        echo $line."<br>";
                    }

            }
}
```

Let's assume that the list.txt contains

ghgh
fghy
Hello
Hellothere

The code above will print only : Hello

What I'm trying to do is to print Hellothere as well as it contains two valid words Hello and there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### (Edited)

You can try to pass constant `PSPELL_RUN_TOGETHER` as option:

```
$pspell_link = pspell_new( "en", Null, Null, Null, PSPELL_RUN_TOGETHER );
```

From PHP documentation:

> The mode parameter is the mode in which spellchecker will work. There are several modes available:
>
> PSPELL_FAST - Fast mode (least number of suggestions)
>
> PSPELL_NORMAL - Normal mode (more suggestions)
>
> PSPELL_BAD_SPELLERS - Slow mode (a lot of suggestions)
>
> PSPELL_RUN_TOGETHER - Consider run-together words as legal compounds. That is, "thecat" will be a legal compound, although there should be a space between the two words. Changing this setting only affects the results returned by pspell_check(); pspell_suggest() will still return suggestions.

Furthermore, replacing all spaces in the `line`, you pass a string like "ghghfghyHelloHellothere" to `pspell_check()`

Try instead exploding:

```
(...)
$words = explode( ' ', $line );
foreach($words as $word)
{
    if (pspell_check($pspell_link, $word)) 
    {
        echo "---> ".$word.PHP_EOL;
    }
}
(...)
```

Comment: I have replaced `$pspell_link = pspell_new("en");` by `$pspell_link = pspell_new( "en", PSPELL_RUN_TOGETHER );` however the Hellothere wasn't printed

Comment: Check edited answer... For me it works

Comment: ... and please note that if there are carriage returns or tabs at the end of the $line last word is omitted! (use `$line = preg_replace('/[\r\n\t]/', '', $line);`)

Comment: Its works perfectly THANK YOU!!!